# How to save session on Wii U?

Tags: php, session, wii-u

I have had problems with running a PHP program I made on Wii U... it seems the session does not save from page to page (as if I never run session_start(); ).  I boiled it down to this short script:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['count']))
{
    $_SESSION['count']=0;
}
var_dump($_SESSION['count']);
$_SESSION['count']++;
```

Which should echo out int(0), next page load int(1), next page load int(2), etc.  However, on Wii U Internet Browser it only shows int(0).

I have found no way to save to a session on the Wii U Internet Browser.  I know it is possible, because logins are saved from page to page.  Is there a configuration issue I'm missing or is it just a problem with my Wii U?

Comment: Evidently early versions of the Wii U browser did not support cookies, and the current version has an option to disable them. You must have cookies enabled for PHP sessions to work.

Comment: @Sammitch I don't think I disabled cookies anywhere though... do you know where it is?

Comment: [I just googled it](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/wii-u/Internet_Browser_Issues).

Comment: Well I just did a few days of searching for nothing :(  I'll try that and see what it does.

Comment: Deleting cookies did not work and I did not see an option to enable/disable them.

Comment: I sent this into Nintendo, I'll see if they reply.

Comment: @iggyvolz did you receive a reply from Nintendo? I also seem to be having trouble with using session cookies on Wii U.

Comment: I never did get a response.  I gave up on the platform for now.